# Angular Unit testing event handle keypress is not returning the right value

Tags: angular, karma-jasmine, karma-runner

I trying to do a unit testing for angular in jasmine test framework for an event of key event. I want to make the index become 0 when the value is less than 0.

```
      if ($event.code === 'ArrowUp') {
          if (this.currentIndex < 0) {
              this.currentIndex = 0;
          } else if (this.currentIndex > 0) {
              this.currentIndex--;
          }
```

```
    it('should return 0 when value is less than 0', () => {
      const event = new KeyboardEvent('ArrowUp', { code: 'ArrowUp' });
      component['currentIndex'] = -5;
      component.handleKeyboardEvents(event);
      expect(component['currentIndex']).toBe(0);
    });
```

it doesnt seem like the value was reassign

Comment: can you elaborate? What is happening, du you get any outputs. What Values du you actually get?

Comment: The output is still -5

Comment: technically not an output but alright. Can you check if the above function is even called? Can you find any logs or something similar that prove the function is  executed?

Comment: So, it doesn't seem like it being called, But I did initialize it to be call.

Comment: Have you tried calling `fixture.detectChanges()`?

Comment: I am not using fixture here